# Need to hide function inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How i can hide  from showing in webpage?
it would be better to use a div or css function?

```
<?php

if ( 'multi' == $type ) {

    echo '<span class="label-group">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Room %s', 'awebooking' ), absint( $i ) ) . '</span>';

}

?>

<div class="apb-field_group">

    <div class="apb-field">

        <label><?php echo AWE_function::get_option( 'label_adult' ) ? esc_html( AWE_function::get_option( 'label_adult' ) ) : esc_html__( 'Adult', 'awebooking' ); ?></label>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asing for. what you mean by hide, what to hide?

Comment: to hide function from displaying in webpage

Comment: You mean your php code is showing on the html page, or maybe you have javascript code somewhere? it's not the code your provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no such thing as a div or a css function.  Div is an HTML markup and CSS is meant for styling (and has no functional capabilities). Semantics aside, you can have an element on the page not display by using:

```
<div style="display:hidden">Don't show this text</div>
```

Or you could use style tag to do this:

```
<style>
.blah {
    display:hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="blah">I AM A SECRET!</div>
```

Or, if you're using PHP, you can check a condition before displaying it:

```
<?php

$shouldDisplayMyDiv = false;

if ($shouldDisplayMyDiv) {
    echo "<div>This div is not sent to the client</div>";
}

?>
```